# Do the Bonus Spells for the Unearthed Arcana version of Storm Sorcerer include extra slots to cast them with?

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer, unearthed-arcana

First time player and spell caster. I'm playing an Air Genasi rogue/sorcerer. One of the other players recommended the storm sorcerer from Unearthed Arcana instead of Xanathar's, because of the bonus spells.

What I don't understand is whether these include extra slots, or are they just spells I know in addition to the spells I would choose as a sorcerer?

(This is not about being potentially overpowered. My DM and I are already discussing that.)

Comment: I believe (although I can't find a definitive statement) that content appearing in Xanathar's Guide is intended to supercede any pre-release versions appearing in Unearthed Arcana.

Comment: Depends on how heavily you want to rules-lawyer it, and like I said, I'm talking about it with my DM. There's a spectrum of people who find it fun to follow the rules and the dice exactly at one end, and people who "rule of cool" at the other. At the end of the day, the setting you're playing in is the DM's world. The rules written by Wizards of the Coast are well-informed, but if your group is toward the "rule of cool" end and following them to the letter makes the setting less enjoyable, then ditch the rule. To paraphrase Gygax, even the dice are in service to the story.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## They are included as Spells Known

The feature Stormborn reads:

> ... you gain the following
>   spells  at  the listed  sorcerer    level.  These   spells  do   not    count   against the number  of  sorcerer    spells   you    know.

The last sentence there seems to imply that they are included in the list of known spells from your Spellcasting feature, although in this case they don't count against you.

You do not gain any spell slots from this feature.

### Balance and Feedback Concerns

In order to be ready for Xanathar's Guide to Everything, the Bonus Spells were removed. There is no way of knowing whether this was for balance reasons or simply due to playtest feedback, but just be aware that the most updated version is the most likely to fit in well with other characters in your game. If no one has a problem with the old iteration, then you can ignore this advice.